# How to automate ISO installation (iDrac for DELL server)?

Tags: user-interface, automation, ui-automation

I need to automate ISO installation on Dell server. For such systems we have host itself and another ip for the [iDrac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC) management interface.

The flow that I need to automate is:

1. Connect a USB with ISO DD image to the system
2. reboot the host (can be done via ssh directly or from iDrac virtual console that connects to the host)
3. After the reboot, I don't have ssh connection to host but in the KVM (virtual console) I can still see the rebooting process and communicate with it. for example pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd> etc.
4. Change the BIOS setup to start from USB and complete the installation by filling all required parameters.

For that purpose I tried using the pywinauto (we have a RobotFramework + Python2.7), but the problem that I'm facing that the KVM (virtual console) is recognized as one window (with no children or other controls).
So I can type keys like: <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> Arrows(<kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd>,<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>) <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd>... but I'm not able to get or read the content of the console shown in the screen, what enforce me to use hardcoded steps and use sleeps between steps.

Something else that I thought that can help is connecting to the iDrac via SSH and with racadm api to try to get that content, but I couldn't find a subcommand that gives such information.

So am out of options, I know about other tool called Sikuli that works with image recognition which I used before to automate iOS and I found the reliability of it hard to trust so am not going to try it again.

Please advise if there is such a tool that can extract that console content.
BTW, the console can be opened with different plug-in types such: Native, Java, Html5 (only in iDrac 8+), even with Html5 the control that contains that console is a `<canvas>` that I can’t really extract anything from it (beside that I need to cover older versions of iDrac)

Comment: There are several open-source tools that can recognize the control by gold image. The most popular one is Sikuli. Its pure Python replacement is [Lackey](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey). It may help in such a complicated case.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Dell.  There are a couple options.  Simplest is to use remote racadm from your script.  You can install racamd on any Windows or Linux machine.  You can use racadm to dispaly boot order then change it and boot the host.

http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/idrac7-8-lifecycle-controller-v2.30.30.30_Reference%20Guide4_en-us.pdf

```
racadm -r <idrac-ip> -u <user> -p <passwd> get BIOS.BiosBootSettings
racadm -r <idrac-ip> -u <user> -p <passwd> set BIOS.BiosBootSettings.HddSeq
racadm -r <idrac-ip> -u <user> -p <passwd> serveraction powerup
```

Other options are wsman and redfish you can learn about those on the Dell Tech Center wiki http://de.community.dell.com/techcenter/w/wiki

Comment: Is there a way to use racadm to tell the machine to boot from an external USB drive?

Comment: Yes pretty sure this will work, but I haven't verified.  I believe the USB Mass storage device will appear in the HddSeq when it is inserted and detected by BIOS.  If the server is already booted you will probably need to insert the USB device and reboot the server so BIOS detects it before you can select it then reboot again.  There is also BIOS.OneTimeBoot settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the desired ISO on a Windows share
2. Install `racadm` tools on your workstation

https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=8gmf6

3. In command line, give the iDRAC command to mount the shared ISO to the server where you want to install the iso content:

```
racadm -r remote_machine_iDRAC_IP -u idrac_user -p idrac_password remoteimage -c -u remote_share_user -p remote_share_passwd -l //remote_share_IP/iso/<iso_name>
```

4. Change boot order:

```
racadm -r remote_machine_iDRAC_IP -u idrac_user -p idrac_password remoteimage -c -u remote_share_user -p remote_share_passwd set idrac.ServerBoot.FirstBootDevice VCD-DVD
```

5. Use powercycle if machine machine is powered up, or powerup if it is powered down:

```
racadm -r remote_machine_iDRAC_IP -u idrac_user -p idrac_password remoteimage -c -u remote_share_user -p remote_share_passwd serveraction powercycle/powerup
```

When you connect to the iDRAC console it should boot (assuming the ISO is a bootable image) to the OS installation screen.

6. Do the installation and right before restarting it following the OS deployment disconnect the mounted ISO:

```
racadm -r remote_machine_iDRAC_IP -u idrac_user -p idrac_password remoteimage -d
```

Answer (score 0):

selecting on f11 boot manager and then click on shot bios menu
 and then selected bootable usb. it is doing automatic